# Как правильно передать параметры через Ajax в action Kohana?

Tags: ajax, kohana

Необходимо передать из jQuery в контроллер  kohana параметры,  для того чтобы сделать на странице постраничную навигацию, записи должны загружаться через Ajax.

Как правильно настроить путь в файле bootstrap.php к необходимому контроллеру, так чтобы он мог получать сразу два get параметра? Параметры: lines - число записей, pages -  количество страниц.

Версия Kohana - 3.1.4

**Код на стороне контроллера**:

```
// Ajax функция - возвращает список таймеров (путь - timerslist)
public function action_timers_list_ajax(){


        // данные из GET запроса       
        $lines = (int) $this->request->query('lines');
        $pages = (int) $this->request->query('pages');

        $data = array(
            'lines'    => $lines,
            'pages'  =>  $pages
        );

        // var_dump($data); 

        json_encode($data);
        exit;      

}
```

Сейчас **код в файле в bootstrap.php**  для экшена  timers_list_ajax выглядит так:

```
Route::set('timerslist', 'timerslist(<controller>(/<action>))')
->defaults(array(
            'directory'  => 'index',
            'controller' => 'timer',
            'action' => 'timers_list_ajax',     
));
```

Как корректно указать вместо id  параметры lines и page?

**Код на стороне jQuery**:

```
 $.ajax({    
    type:"GET",
    url: "my_project/timerslist",  
    data: {"lines": 10, "pages": 1},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(response){ console.log(response);});
```

Answer (score 1):

В роуте пропишите параметры (если они обязательные то уберите скобки)

```
Route::set('timerslist', 'timerslist(/<lines>(/<pages>))')
->defaults(array(
            'directory'  => 'index',
            'controller' => 'timer',
            'action' => 'timers_list_ajax',     
));
```

В контроллере берете данные из URL

```
$lines = $this->request->param('lines');
$pages = $this->request->param('pages');
```

Ajax так:

```
var lines=10, pages=1;
$.ajax({    
    type:"GET",
    url: "/timerslist/"+lines+"/"+pages,  
    data: {},
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: "json"
}).done(function(response){ console.log(response);});
```

То есть параметры передаёте прямо в URL и вызываете этот URL ajax'ом